# Angular ng-repeat and ng-show for pulling individual data from JSON

Tags: json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-show

I have a carousel and want to display the title and description of three items pulling the data from my JSON file by the unique code. Is it possible to use a ng-show to say 'if this equals code01 then display the other data for that item'. I have written some code of what I think should work, but doesn't.

```
<div id="slider-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#slider-carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#slider-carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#slider-carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <div ng-repeat="product in store.products">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
                <div ng-show="product.code === code01">
                    <h1><product-title></product-title></h1>
                    <p><product-description></product-description> </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div ng-show="product.code === code02">
                    <h1><product-title></product-title></h1>
                    <p><product-description></product-description> </p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="item">
                <div ng-show="product.code === code03">
                    <h1><product-title></product-title></h1>
                    <p><product-description></product-description> </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <a href="#slider-carousel" class="left control-carousel hidden-xs" data-slide="prev">
        <i class="icon icon-arrow-circle-left"></i>
    </a>
    <a href="#slider-carousel" class="right control-carousel hidden-xs" data-slide="next">
        <i class="icon icon-arrow-circle-right"></i>
    </a>
</div>
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing that jumps out at me is the lack of quotes around the 'codes' in your ng-show statements. Try:

`ng-show="product.code === 'code01'"`

This way you're comparing product.code to the string 'code01'.

To add to this, I noticed something you may be able to clean up as well. The following html is repeated three times (once for each 'code'):

```
<div ng-show="product.code === code01">
  <h1><product-title></product-title></h1>
  <p><product-description></product-description> </p>
</div>
```

You can use boolean expressions in `ng-show`, so instead of separate html blocks for each code you could write it once as:

```
<div ng-show="product.code === 'code01' || product.code === 'code02' || product.code === 'code03'">
  <h1><product-title></product-title></h1>
  <p><product-description></product-description> </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put quotes around the value in your ng-show, so:

```
ng-show="product.code === 'code01'"
```

That should work.